# How I get the Attributevalue from a Xml to a Array with Linq to XML?

Tags: asp.net, xml, linq, arraylist, linq-to-xml

hi i want to get a arralist from a xml file with Linq to XML

here my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>

<modules>
  <modul name=""></modul>
  <modul name="P1:"></modul>
  <modul name="AS5050:"></modul>
  <modul name="GMS4010:"></modul>
  <modul name="GMS4020:"></modul>
  <modul name="GMS4030A:"></modul>
  <modul name="gateway:"></modul>
  <modul name="view_only:"></modul>
</modules>
```

here my code:

```
private ArrayList GetModules() 
{
    XDocument x = XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath(@"~\App_Data\UGNX.xml"));
    ArrayList data = from item in x.Elements("modul") ///??? 
    return data; 
}
```

Comment: Any reason you want to use `ArrayList` rather than a generic collection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you want:

```
private List<string> GetModules() {
    return XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath(@"~\App_Data\UGNX.xml")
                    .Root               // Root element
                    .Elements("modul")  // Select child "modul" elements
                    .Attributes("name") // Select "names" attributes within them
                    .Select(attribute => (string) attribute) // Fetch the values
                    .ToList();          // Convert to a list of strings
}
```

I'd *strongly* recommend the use of a generic collection here rather than `ArrayList`.

Make sure that you understand each line of this solution, so that in the future you can come up with similar code yourself.